# C++: Accessing a struct's non-static member attributes through the struct

Tags: c++, types, metaprogramming

I want to fill instances of certain `struct`s from key-value-pairs read from a file. For this purpose I want to provide a function that lets the user define which key should be associated to which member of a struct without having an instance of that struct yet.

A very simplified example to illustrate the idea would be (please consider it pseudo code as it doesn't work in C++):

```
struct Foo {
    int bar;
    int baz;
}

template<M, S>
void map2member(const std::string& memberKey, M& member);

int main() {
    ...
    map2member<Foo>("bar", Foo::bar);
    map2member<Foo>("baz", Foo::baz);
    ...
}
```

So, calling `map2member()` creates a setup about how to transfer the content of a file into data structures. At this point there aren't already instances, but `Foo` as a type and its structure is known. The instances will be created and populated later on during parsing the file. The keys in the file contain sufficient information to do so, e.g. `foo1.bar = 123`, `foo1.baz = 456`, `foo2.bar = ...` (just to give some context).

Using `Foo::bar` in the way shown above of course raises an error that a non-static member cannot be used in this way. Now the big question is: Is there a way to express "access `Foo::bar` on a given instance of `Foo`"? Maybe with some metaprogramming technique that I missed so far?

Alternatives that came to my mind are to add the requirement for extra functionality in the target structures that handles the mapping of member names to the members attributes. Another option is to change `map2member()` to accept a callback provided by the user (my favourite atm) which is called with an actual instance then. But even if I'll probably go for the callback solution, I'm still curious if my initial idea is feasible or completely impossible.

Comment: If all your members have the same type, you are looking for pointers-to-member, `&Foo::bar` and `&Foo::baz` in your case. If the types are different, things get a *lot* more complicated.

Comment: Why you tagged it language-lawyer, do you want quotes from ISO standard? there is hardly a single line, it would be veeery lengthly sequence of quotes from there

Comment: @j6t, it's not that much more complicated. All the parts can be made templates as needed in a fairly straightforward way.

Comment: I see no problem passing pointers to members around and you can use `std::invoke` to set or get member pointers. The problem is how you store the pointers in a map when they have different types. Maps usually need to be homogeneous. You could probably come up with a solution to get it to work, but it's not worth the effort: There are simpler ways to get serialization to work. Serialization libraries often provide a templated (de)serialize function that can be specialized for custom types, see e.g. [here](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial#converting-tofrom-native-data-types)

Comment: You probably want to get  familiar with the concept of pointer-to-member, it is exactly the "access the bar member on any given instance of Foo" thing.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Seems like I misinterpreted the meaning of the language-lawyer tag after I found it in the context of another question. I already was not sure to use it but it made its way to the question. Anyways, following your suggestion I removed it.

Comment: @joergbrech or code generators. There are patterns that rely on this though, usually eveny processing, operating via method of common base class, meta class to which a pointer-to-member would be passed. Qt 5 is a big example of such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `Foo::bar` doesn't denote any entity you can take a reference of. `Foo` is not a namespace, it is a class name, and `bar` is not a name of static member of that class. So `Foo::bar` is a qualified name of a non-static class member.

A non-static member is a subobject of type `Foo` object, the former doesn't exist apart from the latter.

As `Foo::bar` doesn't denote an object entity, you can't take address of that as an address of some type M object to bind with the formal parameter `M& member`. To take an address of subobject, you must use an instance of object. But C++ got an additional concept of a pointer-to-member specifically to denote members within a class-type.
The signature of `map2member` which takes a pointer-to-member as second argument in template form would look like this:

```
template<typename M, typename S>
void map2member(const std::string& memberKey, S M::* member);
```

The token `S M::*` can be read as *"pointer to a member of class M, which got type S"*. To have that member accessed you must use operators `.*` or `->*`. Note that these are stand-alone operators, not  some sequences of  access and dereference operator.

```
Foo bar;
bar.*member = 42;
```

As a function is a correct type, a poiner-to-member can  be a pointer to non-static function. You may think of pointer-to-member as of a abstract offset from within of class structure, the big difference that it is correctly working for non-POD structures, member functions and virtual members.

To form a pointer-to-member value, one should use `operator&`, just like to get a pointer:

```
map2member<Foo>("bar", &Foo::bar);
```

The template parameter `M` would be deduced as `Foo` and template parameter `S` would be substituted by type of `bar` as it was declared within class, an `int` in your case.

If `bar` is static, the expression `&Foo::bar` would yeld a normal pointer, because `bar` is not a sub-object. If a `foo` is member function of type `F`, same rule applies: in case of non-static `foo` an expression `Foo::foo` yields a pointer-to-member `F Foo::*`, while static one would yield a function pointer `F*`.

To avoid confusion (and possible ambiguity in template code), C++ forbids using an expression in form of `Foo::bar` to get a pointer to mebmer, even if bar would be a member-function (therefore pointers, pointers-to-function, and pointers-to-member are governed by differentrules and are different type cathegories).

TLDR. There is no a reference-to-member. To have a reference, you need an object first.

Comment: I'll definitely give it try. I've never used this concept so far, so I'm happy to learn something new :) Many thanks also to the ones who pointed in this direction in their comments!